# php registration form not working properly

Tags: php, webforms, registration

I am using Apache 2.4.3, MySQL 5.5.27, PHP 5.4.7, phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2. Please help me I can't go further without knowing this. In my code below I have `$errors[]='All fields required';` and this won't work for me. It won't show any errors until I change it to `echo 'All fields required';`. But this code was taken from a video tutorial and it worked for him.
Can anyone tell me the reason it's not working for me?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include 'ini.php';
?>

<form action="register.php" method="post">
   <p>Username:<br/><input type="text" name="reg_u_name" maxlength="20" ></p> 
   <p>Password:<br/><input type="password" name="reg_password" maxlength="20" ></p>
   <p><input type ="submit" value="Register" ></p>
</form>

<?php
if (isset( $_POST['reg_u_name'], $_POST['reg_password'] )) {
   $reg_u_name = $_POST['reg_u_name'];
   $reg_password = $_POST['reg_password'];

   $errors = array();

   if (empty($reg_u_name) || empty($reg_password)) {
      $errors[] = 'All fields required';
   } else {
      if (strlen($reg_u_name) > 50 || strlen($reg_password) > 50) {
         $errors[] = 'One or more fields contains too many characters';
      }
   }
}
?>
```

If anyone giving negative votes pls tell the reason

Answer (score 1):

After your if-conidtion try to put this code:

```
foreach($errors as $error) {
  echo "$error<br/>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in same page then the form action will be blank

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: thats ok can you tell why the $errors[] wont work and echos work

Comment: i remove the $errors and put echo there not in the first $errors in second and third

Comment: @So which part it echoes `All fields required` OR `One or more fields contains too many characters`?

Comment: if i leave the form blank it show All fields required and if i fill more than 50 characters it shows One or more fields contains too many characters

Comment: So what is the problem here, you have make condition for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put error message ''All fields required' into an array, you need to print that array

like this

```
 print_r($errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( isset ( $_POST['reg_u_name']) && isset($_POST['reg_password'])) {
echo $reg_u_name = $_POST['reg_u_name'];
echo $reg_password = $_POST['reg_password'];

$errors = array();

if (empty($reg_u_name) || empty($reg_password)) {
    $errors[0]= 'All fields required';
}else{
    if (strlen($reg_u_name) > 50 || strlen($reg_password) > 50){
        $errors[0]= 'One or more fields contains too many characters';
    }
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($errors); echo '<pre>';
}
```

working now

Comment: $errors[] = '...'; is perfectly valid. It appends the assigned value to the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( isset( $_POST['reg_u_name']) && isset($_POST['reg_password']) ) {
```

plz try to use this one